# How to define the begin and the end value in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, count

I have an array like this:

600

250

600

600

600

I want to define the begin and the end indexes of this array where the value is greather than 500.
I made a variable which value is 2, because there are two section in my array where the values are greather than 500 (1-1 and 3-5).

So how could I output this:

1 1 3 5

The first 1 means the begin index is 1, the second 1 means the end index is also 1.
The 3 means the next section begin index where the value is greather than 500 is 3.
And the 5 means the end index of the second section is 5.

Comment: Unfortunately your question makes no sense. Consider rephrasing it so that people can understand it.

Comment: show some code, as written this question is nonsense.

Comment: He wants the range of location indices where the stored value is greater than 500.  Those indices (in his example above) are 1 to 1 and 3 to 5.  Then, he wants to have us write the code for him :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>

    int main()
    {
        std::vector<int> v;
        v.push_back(10);
        v.push_back(200);
        v.push_back(170);
        v.push_back(160);
        v.push_back(20);
        v.push_back(300);
        v.push_back(12);
        v.push_back(230);

        std::vector<int> indexes;
        int limit = 150;

        bool started = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
        {
            int value = v[i];

            if (value > limit && !started)
            {
                started = true;
                indexes.push_back(i);
            }
            else if (value < limit && started)
            {
                started = false;
                indexes.push_back(i - 1);
            }
        }

        if (started)
            indexes.push_back(v.size() - 1);

        for (int i = 0; i < indexes.size(); i++)
        {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
                std::cout << indexes[i] << "-";
            else
                std::cout << indexes[i] << "; ";
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Here limit is 150, but you can change it. Output is

`1-3; 5-5; 7-7;`

Good luck :)

Comment: It is almost good, but if the last element is bigger than the limit it is output nothing.

Comment: @BusinessMan fixed :) Check now :)

Comment: It works well, but if I change the 7. element value bigger than 150 it won't work, but thank you very much!

Comment: But if you know what is wrong and tell me i will be really happy :)

Comment: Ok, I fixed this problem I think. Good bye :)

Answer (score 1):

Using std:

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::size_t, std::size_t>>
compute_range_greater_than(const std::vector<int>& v, int threshold)
{
    std::vector<std::pair<std::size_t, std::size_t>> res;

    for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); /*Empty*/)
    {
        auto beg = std::find_if(it, v.end(), [=](int i) { return !(i < threshold); });
        if (beg == v.end()) {
            return res;
        }
        it = std::find_if(beg, v.end(), [=](int i) { return i < threshold; });
        // using 1-index
        res.push_back({1 + std::distance(v.begin(), beg), std::distance(v.begin(), it)});
    }
    return res;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/JKE0Ef)

Comment: Nice one. I can read such code, but I am afraid it will take me another couple of years before I can write something like this intuitively.

Answer (score 0):

You really should consider improving your question by better explaining what you want to do and by providing code that you already wrote (and if you didnt you should do it). However, I am in a good mood, so here you go:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct BeginAndEndIndex{
    int begin;
    int end;
    BeginAndEndIndex(int begin) : begin(begin),end(begin) {}
};
typdef std::vector<BeginAndEndIndex> IndexV;
typdef std::vector<int> IV;
IndexV findBeginAndEndIndex(const IV& in,int threshold){
    IndexV result;
    bool isBiggerThanThreshold = false;
    for (int i=0;i<in.size();i++){
        if (!isBiggerThanThreshold) {
            if (in[i]>threshold){ 
                result.push_back(BeginAndEndIndex(i)); 
                isBiggerThanThreshold = true;
            }
        } else {
            if (in[i]<threshold){ 
                result.back().end = i-1;
                isBiggerThanThreshold = false;
            }
        }
    }
    if (isBiggerThanThreshold){result.back().end = in.size()-1;}
    return result;
}

int main(void) {
    IV foo {600,250,600,600,600};
    IndexV bar = findBeginAndEndIndex(foo,500);

    for (int i=0;i<bar.size();i++){
        std::cout << bar[i].begin << "  " << bar[i].end << std::endl;
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

I am pretty sure that there is a more elegant way to implement it by using std::algorithms.

Comment: I provide a solution using std

Answer (score 0):

Just in straight C and not storing the indices anywhere, the following code produces the exact output that you are asking for:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int values[] = {600, 250, 600, 600, 600};
  int threshhold = 500;
  int begIndex = -1;
  int endIndex = -1;
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < sizeof(values)/sizeof(values[0]); i++)
  {
    if (values[i] > threshhold)
    {
      if (begIndex < 0)
      {
        begIndex = i;
      }
      endIndex = i;
    }
    else if (begIndex >= 0)
    {
      printf("%d %d ", begIndex + 1, endIndex + 1);
      begIndex = endIndex = -1;
    }
  }
  if (begIndex >= 0)
    printf("%d %d", begIndex + 1, endIndex + 1);
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Keep in mind the arrays in C/C++ start at zero, not one.  Changing the above code to store the begIndex and endIndex pairs should be a trivial operation.